# Bash Shell Check passes script but at runtime syntax error: operand expected

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# login x times and calculate avg login time, take note of slowest time and # of logins > 1s

function login() {

  startTime=$(date +%s)
  curl --location --request GET 'http://www.example.com'
  endTime=$(date +%s)

  local callDuration=$(expr $endTime - $startTime)
  echo "$callDuration"

}

numLogins=5
allCallDurations=()

echo "starting logins"
for i in $(seq $numLogins)
do

  modu=$(expr $i % 20)
  if [ $modu -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "20 more calls were made"
  fi

  duration=$(login)
  allCallDurations+=($duration)

done

avgDuration=$(expr $allCallDuration / $numLogins)

slowest=${allCallDurations[0]}
numSlowLogins=0
for i in $(seq $numLogins)
do

  if (( slowest > ${allCallDurations[$i]} )); then
    slowest=${allCallDurations[$i]}
  fi

  if (( ${allCallDurations[$i]} > 1 )); then
    numSlowLogins=$(expr $numSlowLogins + 1)
  fi

done

echo "finished:"
echo "average call duration (s): $avgDuration"
echo "slowest call (s):          $slowest"
echo "# calls > 1 second:        $numSlowLogins"
```

The idea is it uses `curl` to make `n` number of HTTP calls to a website (here I use example.com but in reality I'm making RESTful calls to my web service's login URL). It calculates the average call duration, the slowest call and the number of calls that took more than a second to return.

When I run this script through [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) it says everything is fine.

But when I run `bash myscript.sh` (that's the name of this script on my Mac OS file system), I get:

```
bash myscript.sh
starting logins
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   772  100   704  100    68   3171    306 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3477
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   772  100   704  100    68   3142    303 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3446
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   772  100   704  100    68   3214    310 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3509
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   772  100   704  100    68   3142    303 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3446
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   772  100   704  100    68   3320    320 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3641
expr: syntax error
myscript.sh: line 45: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0")
myscript.sh: line 49: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0 > 1 ")
myscript.sh: line 45: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0")
myscript.sh: line 49: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}1 > 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{"json":"coming-back-from-server"}1 > 1 ")
myscript.sh: line 45: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0")
myscript.sh: line 49: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0 > 1 ")
myscript.sh: line 45: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0")
myscript.sh: line 49: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0 > 1 ")
myscript.sh: line 45: {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0")
myscript.sh: line 49: > 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 1 ")
finished:
average call duration (s): 
slowest call (s):          {"json":"coming-back-from-server"}0
# calls > 1 second:        0
```

Where `{"json":"coming-back-from-server"}` is just a placeholder for the *actual* json coming back from each curl execution, however its important to note that it is in fact printing JSON values for all of these.

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry, and why its failing whereas Shell Check says its good (I mean SC has a few *warnings* but no **errors**)?

Comment: `expr` is not bash syntax; shellcheck doesn't check it. (And you shouldn't be using it at all).

Comment: ...ever since the early 90s, when POSIX.2 was published, standard-compliant shells have been required to support `$(( ))` for arithmetic expansion. Use it.

Comment: Also, use `bash -x yourscript` to enable trace-level logging. That way you can both (1) see which of your variables are unexpectedly empty, and (2) trace back to when that variable should have been assigned to figure out _why_ it's unexpectedly empty.

Comment: (And don't use `seq`; it's not part of bash, it's not defined by POSIX, it's completely up to your OS vendor whether it works at all and what if anything it does; and bash has perfectly good syntax for C-like for loops, in the form of `for ((i=0; i<numLogins; i++)); do`

Comment: BTW, re `function funcname() {`, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete (there are relevant entries in both first and third tables); the modern syntax is just `funcname() {`

Comment: `bash` can only handle integer math so this - `avgDuration=$(expr $allCallDuration / $numLogins)` - will likely end up storing the 'wrong' (integer) value in `avgDuration`; you'll want to look at using something else to generate non-integer value (eg, `bc`, `awk`, etc) which can then be stored in `avgDuration`

Comment: not sure where this - `expr: not a decimal number: 'duration'` - is coming from (ie, I don't see any code corresponding to this message), but the line numbers mentioned in your error messages are off by ~5 when compared with the line numbers I see when cutting-n-pasting your code into shellcheck.net; at this point I'm guessing the code posted here is not an exact copy of what's in your script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Charles Duffy has pointed out, `shellcheck` cannot diagnose runtime errors/issues.

In this case the `allCallDurations[]` array appears to be empty and this ties back to a typo in the program, consider the following spellings:

```
allCallDurations=()                # array name ends in 's'

allCallDuration+=(duration)        # missing 's' on end of array name

${allCallDurations[x]}             # array name ends in 's'; multiple references
```

You're actually building a different array (`allCallDuration` - no trailing `s`) from what is referenced in the rest of the code (`allCallDurations` - trailing `s`).

So, fix the one typo and then see what happens:

```
# replace:

allCallDuration+=(duration) 

# with:

allCallDurations+=(duration)    
               ^-----
```

**NOTE:** I wouldn't expect `shellcheck` to flag this issue since, technically, you are allowed to have 2 arrays with differeing names, even if the difference is a single trailing `s`

OK, so I can guess what the next couple issues may be ...

What's the difference in the following:

```
allCallDurations+=(duration)          # previously suggested edit

allCallDurations+=($duration)         # additional edit?
```

What do you think a call to `login()` should be returning? What happens if you call `login()` from the command prompt, ie, does it return what you're expecting?

Comment: Thanks @markp-fuso (+1) -- I made your changes but am getting different errors now; if you have a chance please see my edits/updates above -- and thank you!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Note that our rules require each question to be about exactly _one_ narrow, specific technical problem. Two different problems should be asked as two different questions -- if this answer is correct for the first problem you asked about, you should accept it and ask a new, separate question with a [mre] tailored to narrowly reproduce only the new error.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
  if (( slowest > ${allCallDurations[$i]} )); then
```

...nothing is invalid syntax until we know at runtime that `${allCallDurations[$i]}` expands to `" "` instead of a number. It can't be detected by static checking.

---

Beyond that: `expr` should not be used in modern code. Use `$(( ))` for integer arithmetic, or `bc` for floating-point arithmetic.